# How do I show passkeys in the autofill prompt when the user taps the "key icon"?

Tags: ios, swift, webauthn, passkey

I'm busy implementing passkeys but I'm encountering an issue with the autofill feature.

According to the WWDC video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10092/ at around 14:30), when the user taps the "key icon" in the quick type bar, the user is presented with a prompt to choose a passkey or password to login, and (very important!) also the ability to "Use Passkey from a Nearby Device...".

[Correct modal that I want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHmhy.png)

However, my app (and most others) only gives the user the ability to choose a password.

[Incorrect modal that currently gets shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeFDY.jpg)

How can I get my app to show the first modal (that includes passkeys)?

- Associated domains is correctly setup
- The correct `textContentType` is set on both the username and password fields
- ASAuthorisation is correctly implemented as per the WWDC video
- I've tried `performRequests()` as well as `performAutoFillAssistedRequests()`, didn't make a difference
- I've tried removing the password field, and only showing the username field - no difference
- Tested on iOS 16.3 and 16.4 - no difference

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how you set up the `ASAuthorizationController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only passkey requests are allowed on the `ASAuthorizationController` when using `performAutoFillAssistedRequests()`

As per the shiny example:

```
// AutoFill-assisted requests only support ASAuthorizationPlatformPublicKeyCredentialAssertionRequest.
```

PS: Remember to cancel this request afterwards! You can do this by storing a reference to the `ASAuthorizationController` (ex. `self.authController = authController`) and when you want to cancel the request then simply call `authController.cancel()`

So the complete solution should look something like this:

```
var authController: ASAuthorizationController?

func beginAutoFillAssistedPasskeySignIn(anchor: ASPresentationAnchor) {
    self.authenticationAnchor = anchor
    
    let publicKeyCredentialProvider = ASAuthorizationPlatformPublicKeyCredentialProvider(relyingPartyIdentifier: domain)
    
    // Fetch the challenge from the server. The challenge needs to be unique for each request.
    let challenge = Data()
    let assertionRequest = publicKeyCredentialProvider.createCredentialAssertionRequest(challenge: challenge)
    
    // AutoFill-assisted requests only support ASAuthorizationPlatformPublicKeyCredentialAssertionRequest.
    let authController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [ assertionRequest ] )
    authController.delegate = self
    authController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authController.performAutoFillAssistedRequests()
    self.authController = authController
}

func cancelAutoFillAssistedPasskeySignIn() {
    if let authController {
        authController.cancel()
        self.authController = nil
    }
}
```